# Making a scrollbar a part of an element using just CSS and/or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar

I have a basic webkit scrollbar set up to make my application use a little more sleeker looking scrollbar than the basic browser one.

```
.k-scheduler-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 8px;
    }

    .k-scheduler-content::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        display:none;
    }

    .k-scheduler-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: rgba(128,128,128, 0.6);
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
```

However, I am wanting the scrollbar to appear on top of the element that is scrollable. Not push it over 8px and take up a void white space next to it.

This image shows what I am after (the scroll bar is part of the element. It is there, but doesn't move or alter the width of the element):

[image]

And this is what I currently have (I got rid of the track, but the scroll bar is still taking up space and pushing the element over to make room for its width):

[image]

Is such a thing possible using CSS/JQuery?

**I can't use any extra plugins. I found JQuery NiceScroll, which did exactly what I want and very easy to use. However, it began having odd negative side effects with my app, and I recently confirmed that script-based scrollbar plugins do indeed have the chance to negatively effect the framework I am using as they alter the DOM and the widgets I am making don't handle it well.

Comment: Are you looking for `position: absolute` ?

Comment: Unfortunately putting `position: absolute;` into my scrollbars did not do anything. And putting `overflow: overlay;` on my element did nothing. My plan was to get it to lay on top of the very right side, then work on a way to fade it in and out only when scrolling. But not sure either is possible with webkit scrollbar :/. I may just have to `display: none;` all of it as a scrollbar isn't entirely necessary, which is why I at least wanted a nicer to look at one that only showed up when actually scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Hope [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qwbypg0e/17/) can get you on the right track. Sadly i don't know how to make it only appear when you scroll tho.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroll-box">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.scroll-box {
  margin-right: -8px;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  display: none;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

.container:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this did help on other elements that I am changing the scroll bar to. Now I can hide it unless the user is actually hovering on that element. This still leaves that white gap where the sidebar is. I am not entirely sure it is possible to get rid of that gap with CSS. Right now I am hiding the scrollbar on my scheduler div entirely, which may be the best I can do :/